# Duplicity restore fails, claiming "disk full", even if there is still much room

Tags: disk-usage, restore, deja-dup, duplicity, df

I'm restoring a big file (~80GB, a virtual machine disk image).

Although I start the restore operation with >145GB disk space, as reported by `df` , the restore aborts with a message that my disk has only 900MB available. After the stoppage, I have a 64GB (partial, unusable) .vdi file in the target directory, while `df` reports that I have 81GB available.

(The latter number really looks like the same number as the size of the file being restored... is it a coincidence? If it checks that it has enough disk space to save the whole file until the end, in practice it would require twice the room!)

How come deja-dup (duplicity) aborts the operation if there is still so much disk space? What should I do to get my file restored?

PS. I saw that at the beginning (so called *preparation*) the available capacity starts to decrease (as reported by `df`) even before seeing any file being written in the target directory. Where does deja-dup (duplicity) write preliminary data, and what does it write? I see that something goes into ~/.cache/deja-dup, but it occupies "only" 2.1GB...

Comment: 64G partial file + 81G available = 145G starting free space. I'm guessing that the file starts in /tmp, then gets moved to its final destination. Do you have another disk/destination that you can restore to? It may restore file fragments, and then have to assemble them into the final .vdi file, and that may be why it's running out of space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

duplicity writes restores into the assigned temp folder. to restore a file it needs at least **2 times it's size**, when there are incrementals. that is because internally it restores the oldest version then uses librsync to rebuild the next version based on that with the diff info avail and so on until the requested date is restored, then the file will be moved to the target file system.

simply set duplicity TEMPDIR to a file system that has ample of space and you will be set.

..ede/duply.net